# The administrator can show the user profile after clicking the user's username

Tags: php, codeigniter

> In my admin's page I i have the list of users..and i want that if i click the username it will redirect me to its profile..
>   this is my admin page view:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">
<tr>
 <th>username</th>
 <th>firstname</th>
     <th>lastname</th>
 <th>email</th>
 <th>usertype</th>
 <th>Action</th>
</tr>
 <?php foreach ($info as $infos): ?>
<tr>
 <td>
  <?php 
   $user=$infos['username']; 
   print_r ($user);
   $this->session->set_userdata($user);
  ?>
  </td>
  <td><?php echo $infos['firstname']?></td>
  <td><?php echo $infos['lastname']?></td>
  <td><?php echo $infos['email']?></td>
 <td><a href="<?php echo base_url()?>users/showuser">Show</a> | <a href="<?php echo      base_url()?>users/deleteuser">Delete</a></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

> part of my controller is this:

```
  public function showuser()
{
    $this->load->helper(array('form','url'));
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->check_isValidated();

    $data['info'] = $this->users_model->user_info();
    $this->load->view('users/showuser',$data);          
}
```

> and in my model:

```
public function user_info()
{
    $this->load->database();
    $this->db->select('username,firstname,lastname,email');
    $user = $this->session->userdata('user');
    $this->db->where('username',$user);
    $query = $this->db->get('users');
    if($query->num_rows > 0)
    {
        $row = $query->row();
        $data = array(
            'firstname' =>$row->firstname,
            'lastname' =>$row->lastname,
            'username' =>$row->username,
            'email' =>$row->email,
        );
        return $data;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
```

> **my problem is that when i click on a certain user it will not show its respective profile instead it will show you the profile of the first user listed in you database.**
> ***how to compare the id in my model***

Comment: I'm not seeing any code that's relevant to your problem. you have to write your code on your own. and if your code is not working you can paste it here so we can help. but asking How can I do something will not get you back your work as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really need to take some time and read some tutorials from the looks of your code because you're going to run into a ton of issues further down the line if you keep going like this. First and foremost is you're loading users by username rather than a unique ID which means I'm guessing that your user table doesn't even have a unique ID which in turn means it's not indexed and therefore will suffer from performance issues eventually.

Anyway that aside onto the question. The first problem is the view. You aren't passing any parameters for which user you want so you're just loading a single function without any parameter every time. Your URL should be something like below, allowing you to pass the right parameter each time.

```
//Again, you really should have a userId that you are passing here.
<a href="<?php echo base_url()?>users/showuser/$infos['username']">Show</a>
```

Then in the model you have issue two, you're passing the username of the logged in user to the database so you are never going to get anyone else's profile. See below:

Controller:

```
//this sets the user to the parameter we added to the url above and passes it to the model function.
$data['info'] = $this->users_model->user_info($this->uri->segment(3));
```

Model:

```
public function user_info($user)
{
// you're now getting the user from the controller like you should be.
$this->load->database();
$this->db->select('username,firstname,lastname,email');
$this->db->where('username',$user);
```

I haven't included all your code, just the relevant parts. Keep in mind while this will fix your immediate problem it does nothing to address the other issues with what you've done. There is no security check meaning anyone that has that URL can see anyone else's profile, there appears to be no ID's etc. Good luck, but really take some time and read as much as you can about database structures and understanding how CI works.